# Swift DragGesture tappable area detects touch outside of view?

Tags: swiftui, gesture

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var progress:Float = 0.3
    
    var body: some View {
        ASlider(progress: $progress)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 40)
    }
}


struct ASlider: View {
    
    @Binding var progress: Float
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * CGFloat(progress / 1))
                
            }
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .contentShape(Rectangle()) <<<---- still detects touches outside the bounds...
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .onChanged({ value in
                print("Touch: \(value)")
                progress = min(max(0, Float(value.location.x / geometry.size.width * 1)), 1)
            }))
        }
        .border(.green)
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the gesture is detected outside of the ZStack bounds.

[image]

The logs show this for example:

> Touch: Value(time: 2001-01-04 15:55:29 +0000, location: (67.0,
> -12.333338419596316), startLocation: (130.3333282470703, -11.333338419596316), velocity: SwiftUI._Velocity<__C.CGSize>(valuePerSecond: (-133.40537913839276,
> 10.334994031205905)))

As you can see the location does detect a negative value for Y for example when tapping above the slider instead of inside.

Why is the gesture detected outside of the view's bounds on which the gesture is added on?

Comment: You can add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` before border to minimize this effect but anyway it detects touch by spot (finger circle) not by dot of pointer.

Comment: Interesting, so, this is documented anywhere? I'll try the content shape now and see what I does.

Comment: I tired using `.contentShape(Rectangle())`, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This issue or I would say free advantage came automatic out of the box when you have just one gesture in your app, Apple API try to make it more user friendly by given more gesture area than developer planed for! There is no way to switch this on or off, but here is a way for you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var progress:Float = 0.3
    
    var body: some View {

        Color.white.onTapGesture { print("white") }
        .overlay(
        
            ASlider(progress: $progress)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 40)
        )
    }
}


struct ASlider: View {
    
    @Binding var progress: Float
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * CGFloat(progress / 1))
            }
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: .zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            print("Touch: \(value)")
                            progress = min(max(0, Float(value.location.x / geometry.size.width * 1)), 1)
                        }))
        }
        .border(Color.green)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "just one gesture"? Is this something you have experienced yourself or is there documentation stating so? Thanks

Comment: You asked: "What do you mean by "just one gesture"?", If you look to your question, you would find JUST 1 gesture in your code. There is no second gesture to get confused about it. So you have just one Gesture in your code! by adding second one as tapGesture like I did you can get the result you want. More info: To fix the issue you need to tell Xcode that there is second gesture use the area for itself, and do not use that area for user friendly gesture. And You can just have the code like this `.onTapGesture { }` and It would still work and solve the issue. There is no oder way around.

Comment: you make some "claims" in your answer, do those come from documentation or is it something you observed in your coding. Claims like "when you have just one gesture", "Apple API try to make it more user friendly by given more gesture area than developer planed for", "There is no way to switch this on or off". Also, I tried to add "coordinateSpace: .local" but didn't seem to affect anything. I'm trying to understand what we know from documentation and what comes from trial and error... Also, the code you have here still detects touches outside the bounds of the view.

Comment: What you are trying to reach? are you writhing an Article or solving your issue? My answer works for me, does not work for you?

Comment: Your answer does not work

Comment: @zumzum: It works for me. Do not forget to delete my code from your app, because it does not work. Use better code instead if you find any. ps: be sure the new answer has documentation!!!